# Can't upgrade to android 8.0 - What are the options

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-8.0-oreo

I currently have an app which target **Android 16** and which has been live for a while.

I'm worried that after the November 1 we'll have a lot of issues and we won't be able to use the play store anymore. Does anyone know if it'll still be possible to send & install the apk directly to the new devices after the changes? Even if we keep targeting 16?

I'm mostly concerned about the fact that we use the **"Google Play services SDK"**. Will there still be a retro compatibility there?
Is it likely to have something like the dropping of the Google Play services **SDK** support like we had for Android Gingerbread and Honeycomb?

We also have a lot of things running in the background (GPS tracking, ...). If we install the apk directly with target 16, would we still be forced to follow the new Background Location Limits? Maybe be integrating the Google service apk directly in the app?

Comment: please note, most of your questions are: you ask **us** what **google** will do. We can't answer them. Even Google probebly will change something till November 1st. If your app is so valuable, you should find couple of days to upgrade it to Android 8 as target SDK. That is the correct solution.

Comment: I understand that the correct solution is to upgrade it. But we aren't talking about a couple of days of work, it would probably takes a lot more than that. We still use eclipse for example and they are a lot of changes that seems really time intensive.

Comment: if you are using only Android java code with no NDK or other weird staff in your app, it is quite easy to upgrade. At least you can re-create the project from scratch into Android Studio. The file structure is quite similar, so you should be able to copy-paste most part of code files and resources. I still think that migrating is the way you should take. I could take a look at the app itself, if you share it's link.